# A track doesn't have duration and doesn't seek unless I play it for the first time

Tags: superpowered

Calling `getDurationMs` on an `AdvancedAudioPlayer` instance always returns 0 before hitting play. Also, calling `setPosition` doesn't work, which makes sense since the song has 0 ms of duration.

After playing for the first time, the duration gets filled with a proper value, and `setPosition` works as expected.

Some code:

```js
// Initialization
this.player = new Superpowered.AdvancedAudioPlayer(
    samplerate,
    2,
    2,
    0,
    0.501,
    2,
    false
)

// When the track is loaded
this.player.openMemory(Superpowered.arrayBufferToWASM(buffer), false, false)

// When the UI thread asks for the duration
this.sendMessageToMainScope({
    data: { duration: this.player.getDurationMs() },
})
```

After calling `this.player.play()`, `this.player.getDurationMs()` starts to give the correct duration value.

Is there an explanation for that? Is there any workaround?

---

I could get the correct duration by using `Superpowered.Decoder`, but having this information is useless because `setPosition` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can only access these values after loading the track, which means playing it. A workaround would be to play the track and instantly pause it to get those values.

Comment: The browsers may not allow auto-playing. I have tried it already, but it's not guaranteed to work.